# Cairo Dock won't start

Tags: dock, cairo

Cairo Dock won't start on Lubuntu 14 or 16 on a PPC G5. It only shows a black rectangle on the bottom left side of the screen and that's it. Tried cairo-dock -c, runs with a terminal window that shows warnings, and when I close the terminal window it disappears. What do I do?

Answer (score 0):

Haven't used Lubuntu but on Ubuntu there is a cairo-dock (GNOME) desktop that I can log into.  Of course you'll lose whatever other panel you have to be replaced by cairo's.